# On dropbox, post a string to be removed

Tags: php, post, find

I am working on a PHP page that:

1. Read the items from db file;
2. Convert the item as dropbox items;
3. Submit the form to remove the selected item; and then
4. Another page remove and write the file

Problem:

1. The removal page can echo the posted string;
2. The removal page cannot remove the posted string from db file; and
3. I tried to hardcode the string on removal page, run the removal page ***directly*** , and the string can be removed from db file.  i.e. from `$str=str_replace($HTTP_POST_VARS["RMBOX"],'',$str);` to  `$str=str_replace('abc@email.com','',$str);`

Code and db file are as follows:

File (named as mailto) contains lines:
    `abc@email.com`

Dropbox page (named as mbox.php) contains lines:

```
<form action="rmbox.php" method="post" name="items">
<?php
$db = "mailto";
?>
<table>
tr><th ALIGN=LEFT>Remove Recipient</th></tr>
<tr><th ALIGN=LEFT>
<select name=RMBOX>
<option selected="selected"></option>
value="<?php
$handle = @fopen($db, 'r');
if ($handle) {
   while (!feof($handle)) {
   $line = fgets($handle, 4096);
   $item = explode('|', $line);
   echo '<option value="' . $item[0] . '">' . $item[0] . '</option>' . "\n";
   }
   fclose($handle);
}
?>
</select>
<th></tr></table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Remove" />
</form>
```

Removal page (named as rmbox.php) contains lines:

```
<?php
$db = "mailto";
$str=implode("\n",file($db));
$fp=fopen($db,'w');
echo $HTTP_POST_VARS["RMBOX"];
$str=str_replace($HTTP_POST_VARS["RMBOX"],'',$str);
fwrite($fp,$str,strlen($str));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem. Below is the code:

```
$item = explode('\n', $line);
```